# In PHP, how does one conditionally format a row based on cell value

Tags: php, html-table, format, row

Given the following code, I want to highlight the row of a table wherein the `$listing->Full == '1'`.

```
<table id="datatable-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th align="center">Qty</th>
         <th align="center">Posted Date</th>
         <th align="center">Expiration</th>
         <th align="center">Full Pkg</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php foreach($listings as $listing): 
         ?>
      <tr>
         <td align="center"><?php echo $listing->quantity; ?></td>
         <td align="center"><?php 
            $pdate = new DateTime($listing->posted_at);
            echo $pdate->format('m/d/y'); ?></td>
         <td align="center"><?php
            $date = new DateTime($listing->expdate);
            echo $date->format('m/d/y'); 
            ?>  
         </td>
         <td align="center"><?php 
            if($listing->full == '1'):
            ?>
            <?php echo "Yes"; ?>
            <?php else:
               ?>
            <?php echo "No"; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
         </td>
         <?php endif; ?>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?> 
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So ideally, the highlight color would be FFFFE6.  Any help  is greatly appreciated. This is an MVC site, so changing the CSS isn't conveniently an option.

Comment: did you try putting that IF statement into the class or style argument and adding the corresponding class or style decleration to change the background-color to the desired color?

Comment: Why should MVC affect whether or not you can change the css?

Comment: Do not directly place styling/formatting code into the html structure. Uses css classes instead and create a custom style sheet file.

Comment: I have a CSS, but Mr. Baker, but I don't want this effort cascaded to the rest of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test before you set the style. Here is an inline example:

```
<?php
if($listing->full == '1'):
?>
<td align="center" style="background:#FFFFE6"> 
    <?php echo "Yes"; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
<td align="center"> 
    <?php echo "No"; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is an example using a class in your CSS:

CSS

```
.highlight {
    background: #FFFFE6;
}
```

PHP/HTML

```
<?php
if($listing->full == '1'):
?>
<td align="center" class="highlight"> 
    <?php echo "Yes"; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
<td align="center"> 
    <?php echo "No"; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```